# Unexpected output in converting from long in C to long in C++ in VS?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

I'm writing a program in C (with a school-specific IDE), then converting it to C++ in Visual Studio. The program in C takes a long variable as user input of 371449635398431 (using the school IDE and a unique compiler function called get_long)   When I copy this to Visual Studio, using cin >> instead of get_long, it interprets the long as 2147483647 unless I make it a long long in VS. Are longs in C different than longs in C++ (with longs in C being equivalent to long long in C++?), or  could a compiler mismatch be causing the issue?

Comment: Please refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your code, together with any possible input and the actual and expected output.

Comment: This will differ between implementations - different compilers and/or different operating systems. The standards only guarantee a lower bound on integer types and different implementations implement different actual bounds/sizes.

Comment: @Jeff on *most* modern Unix systems `long` will be 8 bytes. But on Windows and some other systems it will indeed be 4 bytes - and that's perfectly OK as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: If you need a 64 bit integer, always, use `int64_t` instead.

Answer (score 6):

The C and C++ standards say that a `long` must have a range of *at least* -2147483647 to +2147483647. (Note that C++20 requires -2147483648 as the minimum).

Microsoft's compiler for Windows has the range for a `long` set to -2147483648 to +2147483647. A typical Unix compiler (gcc on rhel for example) has a 64 bit type for a `long`.

The motivation for keeping the `long` as a 32 bit type on Windows 64 bit was for backward compatibility. It was *really* easy to convert Win32 applications to Win64 applications, back in the day.

Answer (score 3):

When the first C Standard was written, it was common for compilers to interpret "long" as the shortest type with at least 32 bits.  When compilers added support for 64-bit types, it was common for "long long" to be the shortest type with at least 64 bits.  Treating things in this way meant that the lack of fixed-length types wasn't really a problem, since code needing a 32-bit type could use "long" on any platform that had a 32-bit integer type.

MSVC has always followed that convention, even when targeting 64-bit platforms.  Some other compilers, however, have decided to change the meaning that `long` had always had on microcomputer-based platforms, so that instead of `long` being 32 bits and `long long` being 64 bits, both would be 64-bit types.

Note, btw, that even on platforms where `long` and `long long` are both 64-bit types, they're not compatible with each other.  If one has some functions that operate on data identified via `long*`, and others that operate on data identified via `long long*`, both clang and gcc will assume that those pointers will never be used to access the same storage.

Comment: @Bathsheba: The first one.  The only one which didn't have any type which was guaranteed to be at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 2):

The size of long depends of compiler, settings, data model and phase of moon (the last reason is a joke). But the long size is at least 32 bit.

If you want to use exact size you can use int64_t. for example.